# Плагин Invector - FSM AI - ИИ ботов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть 2 скрипта : **ScaleIncreaseNPC**,**ScaleIncreaseFSM**.
**ScaleIncreaseNPC** - обычный сценарий в котором логика на запуск корутины, которая каждые N-секунд добавляет N-значения к приватной  переменной `int _scaleIncrease`. К данной переменной есть публичное свойство `read only ScaleIncrease => _scaleIncrease.`

**ScaleIncreaseFSM** - сценарий (Decision, возврат true/false), который создается внутри AI FMS и имеет следующую структуру:

```cs
public class ScaleIncreaseFSM : vStateDecision
    {
        public override string categoryName
        {
            get { return "MyCustomDecisions/"; }
        }

        public override string defaultName
        {
            get { return "ScaleInscreen"; }
        }
      
        public override bool Decide(vIFSMBehaviourController fsmBehaviour)
        {         
            return true;
        }
    }
```

По идее, метод `Decide` вызывается каждый кадр. Он проверяет значения и по итогу возвращает true/false.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин выше — "поведение ИИ - Behaviour FSM AI" плагина `Invector`. В `AnyState` находятся проверки состояний других bool. Например, первая проверка называется `SeePlayerOnMask`. Чтобы логика пошла дальше, внутри должны быть все проверки true. (например, видит ли таргет; имеет ли найденный таргет определенный нужный тег; был ли звук выстрела рядом и пр.) Если всё верно, то логика идет до первого выходного блока, на котором висит сценарий  `ScaleIncreaseFSM`. Он должен реализовывать в себе логику на проверку поля `ScaleIncrease` из класса `ScaleIncreaseNPC`. Если бы это было без плагина `Invector`, то в этом случае создалось бы поле типа `ScaleIncreaseNPC` c именем `_scaleIncreaseNPC`. В `Start` я сделал бы поле GetComponent. Но в данном скрипте нельзя объявить метод `Start()`, но есть `Awake/OnEnable/OnDisable/OnValidate`. Во всех этих методах нельзя сделать `GetComponent`.

Он работает в методе `Decide`, но, как я писал выше, он вызывается каждый кадр — из-за этого вызывать его неоптимизированно. Да, и еще суть в том, что если делать просто `GetComponent` в `Decide`, то он будет брать компонент не с текущего NPC, а с первого, на котором есть точно такое же поведение. При использовании `TryGetComponent` он берет компонент с текущего NPC. Я пытался для небольшой оптимизации (когда делал через простой `GetComponent`) сделать проверку на null. Выходит так, что поле становилось не null, но значение он взял всего 1 раз, при первом вызове метода. Вышло так,что значение в `ScaleIncreaseNPC` изменилось,но из поля значения не получались больше.

Как читать значение из `ScaleIncreaseNPC` в `ScaleIncreaseFSM` оптимизированно?

Comment: А можно ли код, приведённый Вами на первом скрине, вынести на скриншотом, а непосредственно как код? Для этого Вы можете сначала нажать на кнопку "Править", затем перенести весь код в тройные косые кавычки типа `.

Comment: Добавил код со скрина